# How to show image in angular where imagename start with dot?

Tags: html, angular

See below screenshot If imagename starts with dot then not able shows image, but if imagename not start with dot then able to see image ?

I want to show if imagename start with dots, how it is possible ?

[image]

TS

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.userService.getFolderDetailsInsideUpperFolder({'folderid' : folderid}).subscribe(
   (data) => {          
     if(data != undefined && data != '' && data.payload != undefined){
       this.uploadedImagesObj = data.payload;
     }
   }
  )
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let imagespayload of uploadedImagesObj">
  <div *ngIf="imagespayload.imageName">
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/images/{{imagespayload.imageName}}" style="height: 60px;width: 60px;"/>
    <span>{{imagespayload.nameOfImage}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Service

```
getFolderDetailsInsideUpperFolder(param){
  return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/getFolderDetailsInsideUpperFolder`,param).map((res: any) => res.json());
}
```

app.js (node.js code)

```
app.post('/getFolderDetailsInsideUpperFolder',function(req,res){
  connection.query(""SELECT folderid, imageName,filesize from create_folder WHERE folderid= ? AND imageName <>''",[req.body.folderid], function (error, results, fields) {
    res.send({
     'status':'1',
     'success': 'true',
     'payload': results,
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not an Angular related problem. Files starting with a dot are hidden files on UNIX like systems because they are usually security-sensitive (.htaccess and .htpasswd etc.), so by default, your HTTP server doesn't serve them to the browser. Check HTTP requests of your app and I am sure you will see 404s for files beginning with a dot.

There are basically two solutions:

1. Avoid saving/serving files starting with a dot (highly recommended)
2. Configure your HTTP server to serve files starting with a dot

Comment: Open your Chrome dev tools and check the network tab. There you can see your HTTP requests.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/images/..........ee.jpg 404 (Not Found) yes I got this.. in dev tools also and in network tab also Michal you are right, now how to resolve this issue if imagename start with dot

Comment: You can reconfigure your HTTP server(s) but that's a stupid solution. Where do you get these files? Do users upload them?

Comment: So probably you need to restrict admin to upload such images or just change the name before upload

Comment: Exactly as @PardeepJain says, validate and restrict the admin input.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a condition from template to check whether name starts with `.` or not, like below -

```
isValidImage(value){
  return value.startsWith('.') ? false : true;
}

<div *ngFor="let imagespayload of uploadedImagesObj">
  <div *ngIf="imagespayload.imageName">
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/images/{{imagespayload.imageName}}" *ngIf='isValidImage(imagespayload.imageName)' style="height: 60px;width: 60px;"/>
    <span>{{imagespayload.nameOfImage}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use this code so this time it hides image block if image start with dot

Comment: Are you really calling a method in Angular template? Isn't it considered anti-pattern?

Comment: @Ankit so what you want when image name started with `.`?

Comment: @PardeepJain if image name start with dot that image also i want to show

Comment: @MichalCumpl not sure, but yes If I put whole logic there in the template then definitely it will be anti-pattern. Can you put some light on this If I am wrong here?

Comment: Just add console log to your method and check how many times is it called and you will see. Read more here for instance: https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16

Comment: @MichalCumpl yes you are right, But If you put the same logic in the template instead then it would be difficult at the time of writing test cases. console many times because this is kind of binding and angular checks every time for new changes, I am always confused actually what to use when.

Comment: Yes, but you can write a directive or pipe for this. That's the Angular way!