# How can I display image with dot at beginning of filename

Tags: javascript, image, filenames, display

Using this code I can't show any image that has a dot at the beginning of the file name
Someone with a solution to this problem?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CreateNewImage()
{
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = "../customLayout_adv/imgCont/.32.1.1.gif";
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(img);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="CreateNewImage();">Create New Image</button>
<div id='container'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Although the question goes for Angular, this answer aims the general js and htp server behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53943331/4636715

Comment: This is not a solution